# Water hose connector

Tags: water, hose

The connector in the wall is broken. What is this called and how difficult is it to install myself? Please see attached image[image] for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the vacuum breaker (part of a normal sillcock) has broken.

It's a one-way valve that keeps water in under pressure, but lets air in when there's a vacuum in the pipe, to prevent siphoning.

Should be trivial to unscrew the remaining plastic from the metal valve body and screw in a new one. Replacements seem to be commonly available for not much cash. There will be  that plastic part, an o-ring type seal between that plastic part and the sillcock, a floating valve part that's usually rubber which goes in before that part is screwed down, and a cap that threads on the outside of that part.

Replacing the whole sillcock is either harder, or much harder, depending on access to the other end and what means was used to connect it. If the vacuum breaker is the only problem with it, not much reason to replace the whole thing.

Comment: I had one that was intact, but leaking. Unscrew, new O-ring, no more leak.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I’m trying to avoid replacing the whole sillcock. However, I’m not able to take it out with the tools I have (like wrench and pliers). Do you have suggestion on how I can unscrew the broken plastic?

Comment: Pliers should work - you could try jamming a (sturdy, not delicate) knife, a punch, or a flat-bladed screwdriver into the inside of the plastic and tap it counterclockwise to get it started. If (as it seems) there's enough sticking up above the metal, file a slot in it (across two sides) and use it to unscrew with a long flat thing in the slot.

Comment: If you can only get one slot in, you can use that as a place to set something that you tap with a hammer.