# Can this frost-free hose bib be repaired? What's the easiest way to get this working again?

Tags: repair, outdoorfaucet

Earlier this spring, a frost-free hose bib was leaking out of the top. I tried taking it apart a little and making sure the O-ring was in place correctly. It seemed fixed at the time and then I didn't use it for a few weeks. Next time I turn the hose valve on I had not yet opened another valve just after the hose bib, and that top popped off somewhat violently. Is there anyway to repair this hose bib or do I need to reinstall a new frost-free hose bib altogether? What parts should I be looking to replace?

As you'll see from these photos, the plastic within the hose bib's top broke into two separate pieces. It's difficult to get the plastic insert out, which makes me concerned I can't just plug a new part in there.

[image: hose bib and top part that came off]

A closer look at the hose bib with its plastic part broke off:

[image: hose bib with broken top]

Here's the top parts that came off, along with a washer - all of which I found scattered about after the eruption when the white plastic part broke.

[image: top parts]

[image: O-ring I found on the ground]

Comment: Can try at a real hardware(not big box) or plumbing store if they have/can get repair parts for it.  Most frost free taps need to be drained of water before freezing to work.  Turn off those small valves for the hoses before the big valve is turned off, and they will burst from freezing.

Comment: There are antisiphon repair kits and also "complete overhaul" kits for these usually in stock at hardware stores.      They cost like $3 so if you're not sure which one to buy just buy them all.  It's also easy and not expensive to replace the whole thing ... *so long as the other end of it is easy to access* it's a 20 minute job.

Comment: @jay613 thanks, I am a very novice plumber so I'd rather not mess with this, but there is easy access + interior shutoff valve + flexible pex tubing on the inside, so this is probably as easy as it gets for replacing a hose faucet. I'll get a few kits and return what I don't end up using.

Comment: @cr0   With that information, the easiest way becomes to be replace the whole faucet.  Only one trip to get a new faucet with no return trips.  Trying to do the repair way would be only slightly harder, but more enjoyable fix.

Comment: Yes this is a perfect beginner project.  Turn off the supply valve and you are free to make mistakes, take your time, and learn without impacting your family.  You can buy a Sharkbite replacement, so you just saw off the old one and shove on the new one.  (If you do that, buy the deburr and depth gauge and learn to use it).

Comment: OTOH if you have easy access to a shut off valve and you're cutting off this hose bib anyway, you could install a drain valve in the basement then you don't need a frost-proof bib. It'll be a little more work but you'll learn a few more things and save a few bucks.  You just need to remember to shut off and drain it from the inside each winter.

Comment: Alright, you've both convinced me to go ahead and replace the faucet myself. I agree this does not need to be a frost-proof bib, as there is a reliable shut-off valve inside anyway. (The interior side of this is the kitchen, with the shut-off under the counter. Anything cold enough to cause a leak with that interior shutoff valve would be a problem with a frost-free bib or not.)

Comment: see: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/250156/18078 - much more work to change the whole thing when all it needs is a new valve that's easy to install.

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks, that's exactly my problem, I had not seen that question.

Comment: @Ecnerwal going off your answer there, I am thinking, what if I just plug up the vacuum breaker? Not sure what to plug it with yet, but I see that some frost-free hose bibs do not include the vacuum breaker at all and I don't think I need it. (I'm on well water, have check valves between this hose and the well.)

Comment: The right parts are not expensive. It's easier to just replace it than to try and change it up. A well system is, if anything, more subject to pressure loss than most municipal systems, and the back-siphoned water does not need to make it all the way to the well to be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-siphon repair kits are inexpensive and easy to install. We can't recommend products here but here is one example - plenty out there.
[image]

The broken plastic in the bib housing should pop out with a little pressure. Try prying it up with a small screwdriver. You have nothing to lose if your thinking about replacing the entire faucet anyway.

Comment: The problem is that the middle part (in the image you shared) broke off while inserted in the hose bib, and I haven't found a way to get it out yet to replace it.

Comment: Following up on this, after reading @Ecnerwal answering this question https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/250155/water-hose-connector/250156#250156 I realized I could push the broken black plastic piece that was stuck in the hose bib, turning it until it unscrewed. Now I'll go get an anti-siphon repair kit

Comment: @Ecnerwal - yours is a better answer than I had.